# Why NASM : Segmentation Fault 11 in macOS?

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, nasm

I am studying NASM on MacOS.

I'm trying to implement a single line spacing using a function, but I have a problem.

```
    SYS_EXIT    equ 0x1
    SYS_READ    equ 0x3
    SYS_WRITE   equ 0x4
    STDIN       equ 0x1
    STDOUT      equ 0x2

segment .data

    Msg_Line        db " ", 0xA, 0x0
    Len_Line        equ $ - Msg_Line

    Msg_FirstPrompt     db "Enter a Digit : "
    Len_FirstPrompt     equ $ - Msg_FirstPrompt

    Msg_SecondPrompt    db "Please Enter a Second Digit : "
    Len_SecondPrompt    equ $ - Msg_SecondPrompt

    Msg_ThirdPrompt     db "The Sum is : "
    Len_ThirdPrompt     equ $ - Msg_ThirdPrompt

segment .bss

    Bss_FirstNumber     resb    2
    Bss_SecondNumber    resb    2
    Bss_Result      resb    1

section .text

    global  EntryPoint

Endl:

    push    dword   eax

    push    dword   Len_Line
    push    dword   Msg_Line
    push    dword   STDOUT

    sub esp,    0x4
    mov eax,    SYS_WRITE

    int 0x80

    pop eax 

    ret 0x4

EntryPoint:

    ; Print First Prompt
    push    dword   Len_FirstPrompt
    push    dword   Msg_FirstPrompt
    push    dword   STDOUT

    sub esp,    0x4
    mov eax,    SYS_WRITE

    int 0x80

    ; Get Digit
    push    dword   2
    push    dword   Bss_FirstNumber
    push    dword   STDIN

    sub esp,    0x4
    mov eax,    SYS_READ

    int 0x80

    ; Print Second Prompt
    push    dword   Len_SecondPrompt
    push    dword   Msg_SecondPrompt
    push    dword   STDOUT

    sub esp,    0x4
    mov eax,    SYS_WRITE

    int 0x80

    ; Get Second Digit
    push    dword   2
    push    dword   Bss_SecondNumber
    push    dword   STDIN

    sub esp,    0x4
    mov eax,    SYS_READ

    int 0x80

    ; +operator use
    mov eax,    [Bss_FirstNumber]
    sub eax,    '0'

    mov ebx,    [Bss_SecondNumber]
    sub ebx,    '0'

    add eax,    ebx
    add eax,    '0'

    mov [Bss_Result], eax

    ; Print Result Prompt
    push    dword   Len_ThirdPrompt
    push    dword   Msg_ThirdPrompt
    push    dword   STDOUT

    sub esp,    0x4
    mov eax,    SYS_WRITE

    int 0x80

    ; Print Result
    push    dword   1
    push    dword   Bss_Result
    push    dword   STDOUT

    sub esp,    0x4
    mov eax,    SYS_WRITE

    int 0x80

    sub esp,    0x4
    call    Endl
    ;push   dword   Len_Line
    ;push   dword   Msg_Line
    ;push   dword   STDOUT

    ;sub    esp,    0x4
    ;mov    eax,    SYS_WRITE

    ;int    0x80

    ; Exit Program
    sub esp,    0x4
    mov eax,    SYS_EXIT

    int 0x80
```

Result :

```
Enter a Digit : 3
Please Enter a Second Digit : 2
The Sum is : 5 
Segmentation fault: 11
```

It works fine if you just write it without calling it as a function.

Why do I get an error if I implement it as a function?

Comment: The issue is that you aren't properly cleaning up the stack after an `int 0x80` call. So if you push 3 arguments (12 bytes) and then adjust the stack by 4 for the system call then you need to add 16 back to ESP after to restore the stack. So for example in your `Endl` try adding the instruction `add esp, 16` right after the `int 0x80` and see what happens. Failure to restore the stack properly will result in the `ret` returning to a bad memory location and likely the cause of the segfault.

Comment: I'd also consider changing the `ret 4` to just a `ret` and removing the unnecessary `sub esp, 4` before the `call Endl`